# Heat equation derivation Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

I was watching a derivation of the heat equation [here](https://youtu.be/AS83QF4X_2M), and at 4:36 he takes the Taylor Series for $q_x|_{x+dx}$, which I think means expanding the function $q_x$ at $x+dx$.

In the video he writes $$q_x|_{x+dx}=q_x|_{x}+\frac{\partial q_x}{\partial x}dx$$

This seemingly conflicts with the definition of the Taylor Series of a function at a point, in this case being

$$q_x({x+dx})=q_x({x+dx})+\frac{\partial q_x}{\partial x}(x-(x+dx))$$

Comment: It's just $q_x|_{x+dx} = q_x(x+dx)$, the vertical bar is used as "evaluated at". The Taylor series is correct. Yours is correct too, but it's around $x+dx$ instead of being around $x$.

Answer (score 1):

It holds
$$
q_x|_{x+dx}=q_x|_x+\left.\frac{\partial q_x}{\partial x}\right|_{x} dx + o(dx)
$$
if you expand around $x$. It holds too
\begin{align}
q_x|_x&=q_x|_{x+dx}+\left.\frac{\partial q_x}{\partial x}\right|_{x+dx} (x-(x+dx)) + o(dx)\\
&=q_x|_{x+dx}-\left.\frac{\partial q_x}{\partial x}\right|_{x+dx} dx + o(dx)
\end{align}
if you expand around $x+dx$ (which is the same).